# Why maven is not working in eclipse indigo?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm trying to make a simple log in/ log out web application with maven and I'm creating the project with the command: " mvn archetype:generate " and choose 341 and it'll be created with the structure below:

**webapp


    -----src/main/java


    -----Referenced Libraries


    -----Maven Dependencies


    -----src


   -----target


  pom.xml**

But when I add some dependencies and update the project something weird happening with the structure of the project according to the picture below:

**webapp


  -----src/main/java


  -----Referenced Libraries


  -----JRE System Library


  -----src


  -----target


pom.xml**

and it's not working any more.

As you can see the the first one has a Maven dependencies Library but the second one has been changed to JRE System Library.

I use mac os lion and eclipse indigo.

Anyone how knows why is like that?

Tancks

Comment: Please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/164138) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer!

Comment: what you mean? I don't understand what you are telling me. Accept what and how?

Comment: Oh tanks now i understand what you mean, sorry it was my bad knowledge of using the site and nothing else. Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean with "choose 341"? I'm not a mac user and create my maven projects via the Eclipse menu File -> New -> Other -> Maven project. This always gives me all necessary files and folders (src main, src test, JRE, Maven dependencies, References libraries, target). What doesn't work anymore after adding a dependency? Any error messages in your Eclipse console?

Comment: As I mentioned before I generate a project by the command line in mac os. And the structure (1) is shown above . But when in terminal write: mvn eclipse:eclipse to download the dependencies or jar files the structure changes after I'm refreshing the project (the second one). I want to know why and what is the problem or what is the mistake I do.

Comment: I use mac os lion and when I use the comman line : mvn archetype:generate, then maven give me a list of more than 500 different project I can choose to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eclipse:eclipse` makes maven re-generate Eclipse .project file which contains the Maven nature. You may want to look at `additionalProjectnatures` parameter or not use `eclipse:eclipse`

**Edit**: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#additionalProjectnatures